# How to include SASS files and CSS files into version repository and developement cycle

Tags: css, version-control, deployment, sass

I have a project that uses Subversion as versioning tool and a remote host for deploy working code (live stage is smth different). I use sass files to generate css files. My question is: where and when should I generate files?

Some opinions:
1. I think it is not OK to put css files into repository
2. I need css files when testing working copy so I can't wait compilation until deploy

Comment: How do you deploy your files that are not in the repo?

Comment: @Benxamin: I would process the css files whenever I deploy the script. Also minify & other stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We choose to version both the sass files, as well as the compiled css files. That way, everyone has access to the latest version of everything when they pull down locally. We build, test and compile locally. Then merge locally. And once it's in good standing, then we push out to a test server (identical to production server).

There is no compilation on the servers. Compiling locally ensures that only valid code gets out to the test server.

Merging locally is made easier because each of us can use our merge tool(s) of choice.

Also, we are able to track histories, and it makes refactoring easier to have both sets of files in the repo.

Finally, The CMSes that we use have modules that combine and minify all the css files into one, and same thing for the js files. We have granular control of the minification process, so we can load them one at a time for debugging on the test server. And turn-off debugging when we want to test production settings.

Comment: I've read that you should never put compiled files in version control.  There has to be more answers to this...

Comment: Putting compiled files into version control allows for easier deployment. But it can be a source of unnecessary merge conflicts. It really depends on how many layers of local, dev, integration, staging and production servers you have, and at which stage you want to compile and push to production.

Comment: For hypermedia, we must version control the built files so that they can be hashed and then cached. It's kind of a best practice.